# No candlestick plot done in the frame

Tags: matplotlib, plot

An exercise that I am doing ends up with a `candelstick` plot after downloading data from Yahoo. I am using the Spyder Python app and `matplotlib` functions. The result I am now gettng is a frame with ticks(which are not correct) and no plot.

As the problem from the error message appears to be in the `mpl_finance` candlestick library I am not sure what to do.

```
from datetime import datetime 
from matplotlib.dates import date2num
from mpl_finance import candlestick_ohlc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f=open("Apple.txt","r")

data={}#Dictionary

header=(f.readline())
header =header.strip("\n")
header=header.split(",")

for name in header:
    data[name]=[]

for line in f:
    line=line.strip("\n").split(",")#info in text format list

    date= [int(x) for x in line[0].split("-")]

    date=datetime(date[0],date[1],date[2])
    date=date2num(date)#for matplotlib

    data['Date'].append(date)#append(line[0])
    data['Open'].append(float(line[1]))
    data['High'].append(float(line[2]))
    data['Low'].append(float(line[3]))
    data['Close'].append(float(line[4]))
    data['Adj Close'].append(float(line[5]))
    data['Volume'].append(int(line[6]))

f.close()

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax=plt.subplot()

plotData=[]
for i in range(len(data['Date'])):
    tempData=[data['Date'][i], #[i] one element at a time
              data['Open'][i],
              data['High'][i],
              data['Low'][i],
              data['Close'][i],
              data['Adj Close'][i],
              data['Volume'][i]]
    plotData.append(tempData)
candlestick_ohlc(ax,tempData)

plt.show()
```

The error msg refers to line 283, which isn't my code. Close data is float and is typed in line 38 of my code. The error msg is:

> File "C:\AnacondaPy\lib\site-packages\mpl_finance.py", line 283, in _candlestick
>       t, open, high, low, close = q[:5]
>
> TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

Comment: You cannot draw a single candle this way. Probably you meant to use `candlestick_ohlc(ax,plotData)` instead?

Comment: Yes you are correct. Just a few moments ago I had realised that I add done that typo.